# Cmake: Exporting subproject targets to main project

Tags: c++, cmake, relocation

I currently have a project called **LIBS** with a structure like this:

```
├── Lib1
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── lib1-class.cpp
│   └── lib1-class.h
├── lib2
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── lib2-class.cpp
│   ├── lib2-class.h
├── cmake
│   └── LIBSConfig.cmake.in
├── CMakeLists.txt
```

in the main cmake file, I have:

```
install(
        TARGETS
        lib1
        lib2
        DESTINATION
        ${PROJECT_DIRNAME_lib}
        EXPORT
        ${PROJECT_NAME}Exports
)

install(
        EXPORT
        ${PROJECT_NAME}Exports
        DESTINATION
        ${PROJECT_DIRNAME_lib}
)
```

as I want to export these in a package that is discoverable by find_package().

My problem is that I generate `lib1` and `lib2` in their respective directories and when installing them, Cmake tells me that

```
Error:install TARGETS given target "lib1" which does not exist in this directory.
```

As suggested [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets#Exporting_from_a_Build_Tree), My understanding is that I should use `Export()` and in lib1 and lib2, have something of the form:

```
export(TARGETS lib1 FILE lib1Exports.cmake)
```

and in the **LIBS** project, have something like this:

```
ADD_LIBRARY(lib1 UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET lib1 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION lib1)
```

However it does not like me using the same name for this library that is being added from the parent project. It tells me:

```
Error:add_library cannot create imported target "lib1" because another target with the same name already exists.
```

so the library is available and I can link to it, etc. if I were to create another target in the parent directory, but I can't install it.

I have found the exact same problem in a bug report [here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14444) but I believe cmake handles things differently now and I am just not doing it correctly. 
So am I doing it wrong? I would like to avoid using external packages if possible.

**Update**: the accepted  solution works only for cases where there is no dependency between lib1, lib2. In that case one should use the solution provided to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103012/cmake-dependency-management-in-a-multi-library-package-export) question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the [bugreport you refer](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14444) to `install()` command should be issued from the same directory where target is created. As you have libraries target created in different directories, you need to assign different export names for them, and, consequently, different export files.

But you are free to include both export files into the `LIBSConfig.cmake` script:

**cmake/LIBSConfig.cmake**:

```
get_filename_component(SELF_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
include(${SELF_DIR}/LIBS-lib1.cmake)
include(${SELF_DIR}/LIBS-lib2.cmake)
```

**lib1/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(lib1 ...)
install(TARGET lib1 EXPORT lib1-export ...)
```

**lib2/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(lib2 ...)
install(TARGET lib2 EXPORT lib2-export ...)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)

install(EXPORT lib1-export FILENAME LIBS-lib1.cmake DESTINATION lib/LIBS)
install(EXPORT lib2-export FILENAME LIBS-lib2.cmake DESTINATION lib/LIBS)
install(FILES cmake/LIBSConfig.cmake DESTINATION lib/LIBS)
```

Note, that [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/export.html) command exports **build** tree. It is usually not suitable for `find_package`, which is normally used for find *installed* files.

Comment: I meant to use export() inside the build tree. It was after I had all the build targets inside the main project that I wanted to install() them as a unified package so that people would be able to find_Package(LIBS). Your method actually installs these targets directly so I won't have to worry about that.

Comment: There is a slight problem with this method. If lib1 depends on lib2, at the build level, we can take care of it by add_dependency(lib1 lib2) but when including the export files, if we don't include them in the right order, we will not be able to satisfy the dependency. How can I include the dependency information of lib1 in the export file?

Comment: I have asked that in a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103012/cmake-dependency-management-in-a-multi-library-package-export feel free to have a look!